# In Arrow Kotlin, what's the replacement for deprecated sequence?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

In the following Arrow Kotlin 1.2.0 code:

```kotlin
val map: List<Either<NonEmptyList<HeroIdError>, HeroId>> = TODO()
val postSequence: Either<NonEmptyList<HeroIdError>, List<HeroId>> = map.sequence()
```

I put the TODO() for clarity.

In the above, the '.sequence()' method is deprecated. [The @Deprecated annotation states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8WiC.png):

> Traverse for Either is being deprecated in favor of Either DSL + NonEmptyList.map.

> Replace with: let<NonEmptyList<A>, Either<E, NonEmptyList<B>>> { nel -> either<E, NonEmptyList<B>> { nel.map<B> { f(it).bind<B>() } } }

> Imports: arrow.core.raise.either

**i don't manage to get anything related to the above to work**: mind sharing an example please?

I tried various combination if map/bind without success (as well as search engine or Bing conversation ChatGPT4 powered).

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please edit the question down to something that is restricted to your issue and can be ran on its own? Ie remove all the database(?) related stuff, and the ScopeKey and DataAccessException etc. Based on the error I guess it's related to this https://arrow-kt.io/learn/quickstart/migration/#traverse, but I don't see how the sequence() call would relate to that, the javadocs also don't show it as deprecated (but the javadocs for arrow aren't great).

Comment: @somethingsomething: i've tried to clarify the issue at hand.

And thanks for the link: digging in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, changing

```
.sequence()
```

to

```
.let { l -> either { l.bindAll() } }
```

now reading the doc to understand the change ^^